# Redirection to newsite in nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, http-redirect

We have an nginx 1.20.1 webserver on Ubuntu 16.04 hosting many sites. One site is oldsite.example.com and while we're building a newsite.example.com we wish for users to start using the new URL (newsite.example.com). We already made a DNS change but wanted clarity on the nginx part. New URL has to work with both HTTP/HTTPS and we have separate SSL cert it as well.

Thank you for reading.

oldsite nginx conf:

```
server {
  server_name        oldsite.example.com
;
  listen                     80;
  if ($host =  oldsite.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  return 404;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
  add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your question about redirection, a simple `302` will do the trick. It is similar to the 301 redirection you are already using:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

And you can return sth. like this, but in your ssl server section:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name newsite.example.com;
  return 302 https://oldsite.example.com$request_uri;
  ...
```

But I would recommend a `proxy_pass`, or just copy & paste your old configs into the new one. It will save you a redirection.

And for all of your misunderstandings about the protocol,

1. There is a `server name indicator`, or `SNI`, in plain text, in a TLS request (at least for now). If you know about the `Host:` header, that is it. You can have multiple HTTPS sites on the same host distinguished by `server_name`, which is exactly what you do for `HTTP` sites.
2. Even for HTTP sites, the `Host:` header is required (for `HTTP/1.1` or higher, but no higher), and the server will look at it. You cannot simply `CNAME` (or sth. similar) a domain into another without modifying server configuration.

> wouldn't the user's browser, when they type newsite.example.com and end up at oldsite.example.com

As I said, there is a `server name indicator` and the server will look at it, as it will look at `Host:` header. You can distinguish different sites on the same host by different server names.

Comment: @mks you know you can do redirection also in ssl server section right

Comment: I like your idea of copying config from oldsite to newsite and enabling it. I think we'll try that.